# asp.net HiddenField: add custom attribute dynamically

Tags: asp.net

How can I add a custom attribute to a HiddenValueField in ASP.NET? Specifically, I need a class="gmapPoint" attribute for a dynamically generated HiddenValue control. This is necessary for a JavaScript on that page

```
var hiddenField = new HiddenField();
hfield.Value = "myValue";
hfield.... Attributes["class"]
```

-- how can I do a similar thing?

Comment: Maybe create a custom control for this purpose?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use [`HtmlInputHidden`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlinputhidden%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control instead of `HiddenField`. It allows programmatic access to the HTML `<input type=hidden>` element on the server and has [`.Attributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlcontrol.attributes.aspx) property:

```
var hiddenField = new HtmlInputHidden();
hiddenField.Value = "myValue";
hiddenField.Attributes["class"] = "a-class-for-a-hidden-field";
```